# How do i setup a api linkedin connection using oAuth and php

Tags: php, oauth, linkedin-api

He there,
I am trying to get a grip on the API of linkedin. What i want to develop is a marketing-dashboard for clients with campagins and there analytics. The documentation on linkedin is not very helpfull (could be me thought). Do i have to be registered as a partner for this? And can anyone help me with some examplefiles or library based on PHP?

Comment: Did you only seach for "linkedin api php" ? First link is very useful : https://github.com/zoonman/linkedin-api-php-client

Comment: Ok, i will get in to this.. one question... Do i have to be registered as a linkedin partner? i allready registered my app in de developersdashboard on linkedin portal

Comment: Just read the link I gave to you, and follow steps. Try by yourself you will learn a lot.

Comment: Ok. I am on my way with zooman. Thanks for the info. Wanted to get some advise before I took a deep dive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the Zoonman tutotial only shows the 'Authorization Code Flow'. For data of campagins and sponsered content on linkedin i need 'Client Credential Flow'. And as i suspected i do need to be partner first to be able to use the LinkedIn Marketing Developer Platform - API.